# When is the exact date for EOL of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, lts

Looking online I can see mention in a cached version of a blog.ubuntu.com post that Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL on 30th April 2019, however it has been updated to just April 2019. What is the official EOL date for 14.04 LTS?

Comment: If won't be before 17-April-2019 (5 years after release date), and yeah I believe 30-April-2019 was mentioned in https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/09/19/extended-security-maintenance-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr , but LTS releases are commonly covered till end-of-month.

Comment: @Pilot6, because "X becomes EOL on April 2019" could be easily interpreted as on 1st April 2019 support stops.

Comment: @guiverc that's what I thought however it would be nice to have an official date somewhere

Comment: Official announcements can be found [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-announce). See https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2019-March/000241.html as an example.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The EOL of Ubuntu 14.04 is on the 17th of April 2019.

To obtain the EOL date of any Ubuntu distro you can use the following [command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/distro-info.1.html)

```
$ ubuntu-distro-info --all -yeol -f 
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" 29
```

It will print the days till support ends. Here 29 days.

To install the command use

```
$ sudo apt install distro-info
```

To get the date, use e.g. the `date` command

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date '+29 day'   
2019-04-17
```

You can automate this with `sed`, e.g. to get a list of currently supported releases with their EOL date:

```
$ ubuntu-distro-info --supported -yeol -f | sed "s/.* \([0-9]*\)/echo -n '           &\r';date -d+\1day +%F/e"
2019-04-17 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty Tahr" 28
2021-04-21 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" 763
2023-04-26 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS "Bionic Beaver" 1498
2019-07-18 Ubuntu 18.10 "Cosmic Cuttlefish" 120
2020-01-18 Ubuntu 19.04 "Disco Dingo" 304
```

Comment: @pgmank the 17th - so it's EOL now.  Remember, abu_bua did this command on the 19th of March, 28 days before 14.04 EOL'd.  (Do this command now and it shows -8 days - 8 days ago, the 17th.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Ubuntu Version History - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_(Trusty_Tahr))

> Normal LTS support is set to continue until 25 April 2019,[[219]](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2019-March/000241.html) after which extended security maintenance will be available to Ubuntu Advantage customers and as a separate commercial purchase, as was the case previously with 12.04.[[220]](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/09/19/extended-security-maintenance-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr)

Considering the above statement normal LTS updates are expected to be received till 25 April '19.

Comment: Seems like Wikipedia is wrong on this. The [article it links to](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/09/19/extended-security-maintenance-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) to support that claim doesn't say 30 April 2019. It says *"...With the end of the five-year LTS, Standard Security Maintenance window for Ubuntu 14.04 approaching in April 2019..."* 14.04 was released on 17th April 2014, so five years later would jibe with the information from `ubuntu-distro-info` in [abu_bua's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126933/6108).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think there is some confusion. [It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-14-04-end-of-life/) also mentioned April 30, '19.

Comment: But doesn't cite a source. Could well be they trusted the WP article! **:-)**

Comment: As per edit, Wikipedia has since updated the text with sources: [Revision as of 11:16, 20 April 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ubuntu_version_history&type=revision&diff=893296122&oldid=893295834)