# Did MySql remove support for installing MySql-5.7 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I've been testing an upgrade path for my Ubuntu 14.04 system to 16.04 and part of that is upgrading from MySql(5.6) to MySql(5.7).

A couple of days ago I ran through a test and had no issues upgrading to 5.7.

Following the steps on 14.04:

- download the mysql-apt-info deb package
- dpkg -i mysql-apt-info_0.8.13-1_all.deb
- set the mysql version to 5.7 in the apt config interface
- apt update
- apt install mysql-server

I know that the mysql-apt-info package creates an apt.conf.d file that tells apt to look at a specific repo for the deb packages. My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` is the following

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty mysql-5.7
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty mysql-tools
#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty mysql-tools-preview
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ trusty mysql-5.7
```

After running apt update and looking at the output of 
`apt-cache policy mysql-server` it doesn't show a candidate for the 5.7 version (only 5.5).

Looking at the repo from a browser `http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty` and navigating the directory I can see that the InRelase and Release files were updated yesterday 07/22/19. Additionally the 5.7 directory has a zero length Packages file. I'm curious if they've updated them to remove support for Ubunutu 14.04.

Comment: Can you upgrade mysql after upgrading to Ubuntu 16?

Comment: I imagine I could but during one of my tests, (without upgrading to 5.7 first) I lost my database data. I found out that upgrading to 5.7 first allowed the 16.04 upgrade to occur without touching my database.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 [has reached End Of Life](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126909/) and is no longer supported here. Unless you are a paid customer of Ubuntu Advantage, you will no longer be receiving security updates. Consider migrating to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to update to 16.04. Should've been done long ago but life happens. My issue is that they removed the 14.04 release for MySql 5.7 in the repo. I wish they just kept the last supported release of 5.7 on the repo for 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the newest release (5.7.27) downloads for Ubuntu https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html#downloads

it appears that this release was not built for Ubuntu 14.04. So I had to download the 5.7.26 bundled deb and use that to install. I don't see any info that they stopped support for 14.04 in the change log or notes which is a little aggravating. I wish the repo would just point to the latest release that supported 14.04. That way you could still upgrade with the repo but just not have the **latest** 5.7.