# I think i deleted some important applications , i cannot see them in the applications menu in top left corner

Tags: 16.04, apt, system, tor

```
sudo apt-get remove tor.
```

I run the above command yes with `.` and it showed me do you want to uninstall tor and its components of 973mb and i clicked yes then half way down i realized tor cant be worth that amount so I pressed ctrl+z, and now i cannot see Google Chrome App Store and some other apps.

How can I fix it?

[image]

following output of the command which i pressed .

Comment: Be aware that 14.014 is [EOL](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126933/931617)

Comment: Time to migrate to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Reinstall all packages that have been removed... Just copy-paste all Packages below "`The following packages will be REMOVED:`". If you closed your terminal, good luck ;-)

Comment: With the new 16.04 tag I'd say this question is on-topic, especially as the same might happen on any `apt`/`apt-get`...

Comment: @DanielMassey that won't work, because `tor.` is recognized as a pattern, and then `apt` will treat it as such and find e.g. `bla-storage-bla` which has nothing to do with `tor`.

Comment: Related: [apt-get remove with wildcard removed way more than expected. why?](https://askubuntu.com/q/210976/22949), [Why does apt removes unwanted packages when giving * as suffix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/431604/22949), and [Ubuntu system is broken after accidentally uninstalling many packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/249367/22949) (especially [Andrea Corbellini's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/249373/22949))

Answer (score 3):

You're lucky, `apt-get`  / `apt` [writes a log](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425809/where-are-the-logs-for-apt-get) at `/var/log/apt/term.log`.

So you can find all your removed packages and reinstall them.

---

As you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, `apt-get` is a stopped process in the brackground. So, frst of all, you should properly end `apt-get`. Simply run `fg` and wait until `apt-get` is done (Yes that will finish removing the packages, but we will be able to get them back).

For others that might find this answer: If you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead, you might need to run `sudo apt install -f` to fix unfinished removals etc.

---

Then, to get back your packages:

1. Find out the exact log time

   ```bsh
   # If it just happened:
   apt_date=$(sudo grep 'Log started' /var/log/apt/term.log | tail -n1)

   # or find manually ...
   sudo less /var/log/apt/term.log
   # ... and set the result as variable, we need in the next step.
   apt_date="Log started: 2019-08-26  16:26:27"
   ```
2. Get all removed packages and reinstall them:

   ```bsh
   # Get all removed packages for this date and reinstall them:
   sudo sed -n "/${apt_date}/,/Log ended/p" /var/log/apt/term.log \
   | awk '/^Removing/{print $2}' \
   | xargs -r sudo apt install
   ```